# adding space between xAxis and svg line D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to add more space between the xAxis label and the ticks so they don't overlap. The ticks themselves also do not fit... Here is the code:

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 100;
const padding = 90; 
const marginTop = 120;
const marginBottom = 120;

const xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(["Response companies", "Food & Beverages", "Proprietary Remedies"])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - padding})`) 
  .call(xAxis) 
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height - padding / 30) + ")"
  )
  .text("Industry Category");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I can't seem to find a way to add more space. The screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

1. You might want to increase the angle at which the labels are drawn:

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 100;
const padding = 90; 
const marginTop = 120;
const marginBottom = 120;

const xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(["Response companies", "Food & Beverages", "Proprietary Remedies"])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - padding})`) 
  .call(xAxis) 
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height - padding / 30) + ")"
  )
  .text("Industry Category");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

2. You might want to simply increase the padding:

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 150;
const padding = 120; 
const marginTop = 120;
const marginBottom = 120;

const xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(["Response companies", "Food & Beverages", "Proprietary Remedies"])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - padding})`) 
  .call(xAxis) 
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height - padding / 30) + ")"
  )
  .text("Industry Category");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

3. Or you might want to calculate the width of the labels and add line breaks for long ones:

```js
const width = 300;
const height = 100;
const padding = 90; 
const marginTop = 120;
const marginBottom = 120;
const font = "10px sans-serif";

/**
 * Measure the width of a text were it to be rendered using a given font.
 *
 * @param text the text to be measured
 * @param font a valid css font value
 *
 * @returns the width of the rendered text in pixels.
 */
function getTextWidth (text, font) {
  const element = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = element.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;

  return context.measureText(text).width;
}

/**
 * Cut a text into lines so that it does not exceed a maximum width when using
 * the given font.
 *
 * @param text the text to be wrapped
 * @param maxWidth the maximum width in pixels
 * @param font a valid CSS font value
 *
 * @returns the text split into lines.
 */
function wrapText(text, maxWidth, font) {
  const remainingWords = text.split(" ");
  const lines = [];
  let currentLine = '',
      word;

  while(remainingWords.length > 0) {
    word = remainingWords[0];
    if(getTextWidth(`${currentLine} ${word}`, font) > maxWidth) {
      // The current line is too long if we add the word
      if(currentLine !== '') {
        lines.push(currentLine);
        currentLine = '';

        // Re-check the last word; continue without removing it
        // from remainingWords
        continue;
      } else {
        // The current line is empty and we don't break up words,
        // so we add the word as a separate line
        lines.push(word);
      }
    } else if(currentLine === '') {
      currentLine = word;
    } else {
      currentLine += ` ${word}`;
    }

    // Remove the first word from the list
    remainingWords.splice(0, 1);
  }

  if(currentLine !== '') {
    lines.push(currentLine);
  }

  return lines;
};

const xScale = d3
  .scalePoint()
  .domain(["Response companies", "Food & Beverages", "Proprietary Remedies"])
  .range([padding, width - padding]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("id", "chart");

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - padding})`) 
  .call(xAxis) 
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)")
  .text(null)
  .selectAll("tspan")
  .data((d) => wrapText(d, 50, font))
  .enter()
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("dy", (d, i) => i * 1.2 + "em")
  .text((d) => d);

svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr(
    "transform",
    "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height - padding / 30) + ")"
  )
  .text("Industry Category");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```